# When is RVO garanteed to apply / does apply with C++20 compilers

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, c++20, rvo

The C++ core guidelines states that

> F.20: For “out” output values, prefer return values to output
>   parameters

But then gives the following exception:

```
struct Package {      // exceptional case: expensive-to-move object
    char header[16];
    char load[2024 - 16];
};

Package fill();       // Bad: large return value
void fill(Package&);  // OK
```

Isn't it supposed to be a case where the return value optimization kicks in ? Is RVO prevented in this case ? Or still not as efficient as passing by reference ? Or is it that some compilers don't manage to do it ?

More generally, when should I **rely** on the compiler optimizing return values as efficiently as the pass-by-reference technique ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Plain" RVO (i.e., returning a prvalue or "temporary" in common parlance) is guaranteed in C++17 and well-supported even before that.

NRVO (i.e., returning a local variable) can be finicky and is not guaranteed, and if it's not performed then you get a move instead. If your move is expensive, you may want to avoid that.

In the example, there's a decent chance that `fill` needs to use the latter.

Comment: Ok I understand now. Fill will presumably construct a default object (so a named object) and then initialize it (with e.g. `std::fill`), which mean we are in the NRVO case, which is not garanteed to be optimized

Answer (score 4):

> Or still not as efficient as passing by reference ?

If RVO applies, then it is equally efficient to return a value, as it is to use an output reference.

> Is RVO prevented in this case?

No. Being "big" does not prevent the object from being RVO'd.

> When is RVO garanteed to apply / does apply with C++20 compilers

A case where it does not apply:

> ... A return statement can involve an invocation of a constructor to perform a copy or move of the operand if it is not a prvalue or if its type differs from the return type of the function.

So, it depends on the implementation of the function whether copy-elision is guaranteed.

The guidelines indeed fail to explain **why** the recommendation should be followed.

Note that the exception says:

> Exceptions
>
> **If a type is expensive to move (e.g., `array<BigPOD>`), consider allocating it on the free store and return a handle (e.g., unique_ptr)**, or passing it in a reference to non-const target object to fill (to be used as an out-parameter).

The highlighted suggestion in the exception makes more sense to me. It makes it clear that the object is too big for stack, and thus reduces the chance stack overflows.